Add two parameter as a integer in dialogflow
I am creating a robot for consulting people with diabetes, I have a flow in which I will calculate the amount of insulin, in the parameters I ask the user for the amount of carbohydrates and the carbohydrate coefficient, I need to divide (the amount of carbohydrates / carbohydrate coefficient) and pass it further to the page, for calculation, how can it be done? Example
Bot: Enter the number of carbohydrates
User: 30
Bot: Enter the insulin sensitivity factor
User: 1.5
# "Data processing (30 / 1.5)"

Bot: You need to inject 20 units
I tried read documentaion and do not  something like this in topic about parameter

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-actions-parameters?hl=es-419

This is how my flow looks like
First, I collect all needed values, I match them with built-in system entity called @sys.number. Here is how the matching intent looks like
In each route I create new parameter to store needed values. When I match carbs, I create parameter $carbs and assign value $session.params.number collecting info about carbs I also convert it to number with built-in function TO_NUMBER "$sys.func.TO_NUMBER($session.params.number)"
Then I do the same with the second value, I store it in parameter sensitivity_factor.
Aditionally, I create a parameter called result where I calculate the quotient with built-in function "$sys.func.DIVIDE($session.params.carbs,$session.params.sensitivity_factor)" and in USER SAYS I display $session.params.result
This parameter will be stored in the session.
You can read more about built-in functions here: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/system-functions
Here is a video on form filling: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sa85lRuCEIs
And documentation about params: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/parameter
